# Modify Getter and Setter with Database First Approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm currently learning ASP.Net MVC 3 with Entity Framework and want to know if there's a way to modify getter and setter for the model class generated by using the database first approach. Say, I want to sanitize HTML in the model's getter and setter to make sure there's no invalid code get saved in database. What's the best way to do that?

Thanks before.

Comment: I think it may be best to do that in code before populating the model

Comment: @Forty-Two: what do you mean? I generated code from empty database so I can implement the model easily, but it looks like I just can't override the getter and setters... Do you mean I can do something before generating the models?

Comment: Well, you said the purpose would be to "make sure there's no invalid code get saved in database".  I would handle that outside the model, not in the getter and setter, whether or not it's actually possible.  You wouldn't need to do that before generating the models, just push the data through some validation logic before saving.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use your custom validation routine. The class will be populated automatically, its up to you to determine then if its valid or not.

Use IValidateableObject or override the ValidateEntity method to handle your own validatations.

See Julie's article at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the edmx diagram you can edit the properties of a, well, property, one of which is the access modifier:

[image]

Comment: This answer actually helped solve my problem - I set setter as private and in the partial class I created a method to populate the property with the extra logic I needed. (The logic I would put in the setter of a non-auto-generated class.)